# Menu dinâmico no Bootstrap com PHP e Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

Possuo no mysql duas tabelas (assuntos e páginas), a tabela páginas tem um campo (assunto_id), que relaciona de qual assunto é aquela página.

Gostaria de montar um menu com submenu no bootstrap

Esta é Tabela assuntos

```
ID  nome_menu_assunto
1   Titulo_1
2   Titulo_2
3   Titulo_3
4   Titulo_4
```

Esta é Tabela paginas

```
ID  assunto_id titulo_menu_pagina
1   2          Titulo...
2   3          Titulo...
3   3          Titulo...
4   4          Titulo...
5   2          Titulo...
6   4          Titulo...
7   3          Titulo...
8   2          Titulo...
```

Este é o script que possuo no php

```
    $assuntos = "SELECT * FROM assuntos";

    $resultado_assuntos = mysqli_query($conexao,$assuntos);

    while ($linha_assunto = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_assuntos)) {

    $subpagina = "SELECT * FROM paginas WHERE assunto_id = {$linha_assunto['id']}";

    $resultado_subpagina = mysqli_query($conexao,$subpagina);

        while ($linha_subpagina = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_subpagina)) {

            if (!isset($linha_subpagina['assunto_id'])) {
                    echo "<li><a href=\"/{$linha_assunto['nome_menu']}\">{$linha_assunto['nome_menu']}</a></li>";
            } else {
                    echo "<li class=\"dropdown\">";
                    echo "<a href=\"\" class=\"dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\" role=\"button\" aria-expanded=\"false\">{$linha_assunto['nome_menu']} <span class=\"caret\"></span></a>";
                    echo "<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\" role=\"menu\">";

                        while ($linha_subpaginas = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_subpagina)) {
                            echo "<li><a href=\"/{$linha_subpaginas['nome_menu']}\">{$linha_subpaginas['nome_menu']}</a></li>";
                        }

                    echo "</ul>";
                    echo "</li>";                       
                }
            }
    }
```

Porém deste jeito, ele mostra como menu, apenas o títlos que possuem indicação no menu assunto_id, e não mostra todas os submenus,

Comment: Acredito que desse jeito deve estar repetindo os assuntos. Você deve colocar o echo do assunto fora do while da subpágina, ou seja, logo abaixo do primeiro while, e não dentro do segundo while como fez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu consegui chegar no resultado que pretendia, este é o script

```
$assuntos = "SELECT * FROM assuntos";
$resultado_assuntos = mysqli_query($conexao,$assuntos);

while ($linha_assunto = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_assuntos)) {

    $linha_assunto_slug = url_slug($linha_assunto['nome_menu']);

    $linha_sem_filho = "<li><a href=\"{$linha_assunto['nome_menu']}\">{$linha_assunto['nome_menu']}</a></li>";

    $subpagina = "SELECT * FROM paginas WHERE assunto_id = {$linha_assunto['id']}";
    $resultado_subpagina = mysqli_query($conexao,$subpagina);

    $fieldinfo=mysqli_fetch_field_direct($resultado_subpagina,1);

    if ($fieldinfo->max_length > 0) {

        echo "<li class=\"dropdown\">";
        echo "<a href=\"\" class=\"dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\" role=\"button\" aria-expanded=\"false\">{$linha_assunto['nome_menu']} <span class=\"caret\"></span></a>";
        echo "<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\" role=\"menu\">";

        while ($linha_subpagina = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_subpagina)) {
        echo "<li><a href=\"{$linha_subpagina['nome_menu']}\">{$linha_subpagina['nome_menu']}</a></li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
        echo "</li>";

        } else {
            echo $linha_sem_filho;
        }                   
}
```